# ERROR: Google Maps API errors - MissingAPIKey/NoApiKeys

Tags: html, css, api, maps

I'm having a problem where my map will load sometimes and other times it won't. The console is giving me different errors, MissingAPIKey and NOApiKeys. I only just got a new APIKey as well. So basically at the moment with:

```
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API-key>&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

it is sometimes loading when I refresh but the console is showing [this.](http://prntscr.com/f8rn8o) I understand that the 'inclusion of multiple API maps' is causing this error, however when I remove `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>` the map doesn't load at all, and can't find 'google.'

I just did another refresh (map didnt load this time) and i got `Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError`as well as `noApiKeys.` I've searched so many forums and nothing is fixing my problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you try looking in incognito in case it is cached to the old key?  Also, you should hide your API key when posting here!

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise! I'm not sure if I understand what you mean completely. I seem to get the same errors in Incognito though.